# Using od command

Tags: c, binary

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *filename = argv[1];
    char *store = malloc(2);

    FILE *fh = fopen(filename, "wb");


    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        sprintf(store, "%u", i);

        if (fh != NULL) {
            fwrite (store, sizeof (store), 1, fh);
        }
    }

    fclose (fh);

    return 0;
}
```

I want my output to look like this -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE6q0.jpg. The output it produces currently is all garabge.

Comment: `char *store = malloc(2);` but you're writing a 2 digit number + nul terminator in it. Please _don't post errors as images_. That's not to be annoying. I currently have to guess your output my firewall is blocking the imgur site.

Comment: also `fwrite (store, sizeof (store), 1, fh);` is wrong, `sizeof(store)` is the size of the pointer, not the data inside it.

Comment: `malloc(2)` is not enough memory. A C string has a NUL terminator (which is a byte with value zero) at the end. So you need at least 3 bytes of memory. And in general, it's a bad idea to allocate precisely the right number of bytes when the buffer is used with functions like `sprintf`. Imagine that you `malloc(3)` at some point that you change 100 to 200. Then, the memory isn't big enough again. The longest number that `sprintf` can generate is 20 bytes (assuming 64-bits), so you should `malloc(32)` just to be on the safe side.

Comment: `if (fh != NULL)` this is way too late. `fh` should be checked immediately after `fopen`. Anyway, `fwrite` is typically used for binary data, not for text. Such as `fwrite (&i, sizeof i, 1, fh);`

Comment: What is "od command"? It does not occur anywhere in the question or code.

Comment: "od" is perhaps "object display"? The linked example output shows that you should be using `fprintf` and not `fwrite`.

Answer (score 1):

The real reason for the garbage is the size of your data on the `fwrite` statement

```
fwrite (store, sizeof (store), 1, fh);
```

`sizeof(store)` is *not* the size of the string. It's the size of the *pointer*.

Aside, allocating 2 bytes for `store` is wrong. You're forgetting that a 2-digit number as a string needs space for a nul-terminator, so you're writing one char too many.

More minor issue: why testing the handle against `NULL` in the loop? you could exit in that case.

Also test the argument length (`argc`).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc<2) exit(1);   // protect against missing arg
    char *filename = argv[1];
    char store[50];  // use auto memory, faster & simpler, don't be shy on the size, don't shave it too close

    FILE *fh = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (fh != NULL) {   // test file handle here, not in the loop

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        // sprintf returns the number of printed chars, use this
        // also use the proper format specifier for int
        int nb_printed = sprintf(store, "%d", i);
        // you may want to check the return value of fwrite...     
        fwrite (store, nb_printed, 1, fh);

    }

    fclose (fh);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this code will create a binary file with all numbers collated:

```
01234567891011...
```

so hardly useable. I would perform a `sprintf(store, "%d ", i);` instead to add spacing between the numbers.

Also note that if you wanted to write characters in a file, you'd be better off with:

```
fprintf(fh,"%d ",i);
```

(but I suppose the main point is to learn to use `fwrite`)